# Cross-thread Winforms control editing

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

how can I edit the text in a windows form element if the code that is editing the text 'belongs' to a seperate thread from the one that contains the windows form? I get the exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code....as this is not enough for us to help you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will need to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method like this:

```
textbox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
   {
     textbox1.Text="some text";
   }));
```

Check this article too: [Threading in UIs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadingDotNet5.aspx)

Comment: Insert `Action y;`  inside the class and execute the code `label1.Invoke(y = () =>  label1.Text = "Any text");`