# Update text box on continuation with Winforms and C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, continuations

C# noob here, coming from experience in other languages.  (Most notably Java).

I'm looking at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114605/how-will-c-5-async-support-help-ui-thread-synchronization-issues?rq=1)'s code.  It's a standard WinForms C# project in VS 2013:

> drop a button and a textbox on the form and use this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => DelayedAdd(5, 10))
        .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 20))
        .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 30))
        .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 50))
        .ContinueWith(t => textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString(),
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private int DelayedAdd(int a, int b)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    return a + b;
}
```

Press the button, wait 2 seconds for the four `DelayedAdd` calls to complete, and the result (115) is displayed in the text box.  **How can I get the result displayed on the text box after every `DelayedAdd` call?**

I tried to shove the final continuation between each call,

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => DelayedAdd(5, 10))
    .ContinueWith(t => textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString(),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

    .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 20))
    .ContinueWith(t => textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString(),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

    .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 30))
    .ContinueWith(t => textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString(),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

    .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 50))
    .ContinueWith(t => textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString(),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

but that fails, I'm guessing because the continuations I inserted don't return the integer result `t`.  I'm such a C# noob that I don't even know how to fix *that*, let alone do this in an idiomatic way.

Comment: What framework version are you using?

Comment: This might be the same question as Yuval, but what is Task? And EventArgs?

Comment: It's out-of-the-box WinForms.  Sorry, thought I mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  If anyone has better/more interesting alternatives, please answer.

First I tried a multiline lambda in place of the erroneous continuations from my question:

```
    .ContinueWith(t => {
        textBox1.Text = t.Result.ToString();
        return t.Result;
    },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
    }
```

That's a tad verbose and repetitive, so I DRYed it up:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // SCHEDULING LOGIC
        Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => DelayedAdd(5, 10))
            .ContinueWith(t => UpdateText(t.Result),
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 20))
            .ContinueWith(t => UpdateText(t.Result),
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 30))
            .ContinueWith(t => UpdateText(t.Result),
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 50))
            .ContinueWith(t => UpdateText(t.Result),
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
    }

    private int UpdateText(int i)
    {
        // UI LOGIC
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        return i;
    }

    private int DelayedAdd(int a, int b)
    {
        // PROCESS LOGIC
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return a + b;
    }
```

Comment: That was going to be my answer!

Answer (score 5):

I'd just change `DelayedAdd` method:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => DelayedAdd(5, 10))
            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 20))
            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 30))
            .ContinueWith(t => DelayedAdd(t.Result, 50));
    }

    private int DelayedAdd(int a, int b)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text = (a + b).ToString()));
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return a + b;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting.  Why the `InvokeRequired` guard?  I have no idea what that is.

Comment: When you want to update your UI from different thread, that's the way to go

Comment: I thought that was already covered by the second `ContinueWith` parameter, `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`?

Comment: Well, you're right. `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` means that you will run your task in UI thread. So you have to use two functions here: one for update UI and another for sleeping. I just wanted to point out that you can use only one function. You can use you very first example from the question, just change `DelayedAdd` method. Look at my edited answer

Comment: I like how little code your solution is. My solution is more verbose because I tried to decouple the blocking method from UI code.  Thanks very much for the crash course!

Comment: You'll definitely want to use and Invoke process to allow other threads to manipulate what you need.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder, why is that?  Do you mean *instead* of `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`, or *in addition* to it?

Comment: @kdbanman
What I usually need is to update the user interface so the user can see the status of the item that is processing. So, you'll need to invoke each control in the Form's `.cs`. That can be done with one method. The one I have tells the form to look for a certain control, specify the string representation of the properties (ie. `ForeGround`), and set that property to an `object` value. Linking another question that answers your basic need to change a form's control from another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562946/cross-thread-winforms-control-editing `WPF is much simpler`