# system.invalidoperationexception cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
        receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
        //Converting byte[] to string
        ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);

        //Adding this message into Listbox
        listMessage.Items.Add("Friend : " + receivedMessage);
        //TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        buffer = new byte[1500];
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this code in my chat application., and this error occurs ,i dont know how to proceed

Comment: first dont put the question in a comment. THats what the question is for. Put the question in the question.

Comment: second - say what platform . Is this winforms xamarin WPF .....

Comment: third say where the error is happening

Comment: ok. Can you help me?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 . I am using 2 laptops to test the chat application when i try to send message to other laptop using this code , this error occurs

Comment: listMessage.Items.Add("Friend : " + receivedMessage);

Comment: is this winforms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread Winforms control editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562946/cross-thread-winforms-control-editing)

Comment: how do i edit my code

Comment: did you read the duplicates? I am not going to repeat what they say, try googling 'winforms cross thread invoke' for more info